# compare 2 arrays and get the values which are not matched :using perl map command or loops simply

Tags: regex, perl

```
arr1 = 1,2,3,4,5;
arr2 = 1,2,3;
```

want to compare and output as `arr3=4,5`;

Please help
thanks in advance

arry::utils error out, looks like some problem with the package, so that option is ruled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub diff_array {
    my ($a1, $a2) = @_;
    my %h;
    @h{@$a2} = ();
    return grep !exists $h{$_}, @$a1;
}

my @arr1 = (1,2,3,4,5);
my @arr2 = (1,2,3);
my @arr3 = diff_array(\@arr1, \@arr2);
```

Comment: `($a2, $a1) = @_ if @$a2 > @$a1;`

Comment: no i dont want to compare the values only take the element, can be string also.